# Forces of an elastic closed string

Tags: waves, string, continuum-mechanics

I want to calculate the forces acting on an element of a closed elastic string and derive a wave equation on a closed string. For this I have already figured out that if the closed shape of the string is uniquely valued wrt to the angle then one can just parameterize the closed string as a "quasi-circle" with a radius that depends on the angle.

I know that for an open string the transversal force is just proportional to the second derivative of the vertical displacement wrt to the position. But I don't think that one can simply replace the derivative wrt to the $x$ coordinate just by the angle, because for an circle with an extremely large Radius the equation approaches that of a linear string. So there must be a dependence on the local curvature. But I am not sure how to proceed in this derivation.

What I have done so far is consider an arc parametrized in polar coordinates.  If I take two points on the arc that are very close to each other then the first point has the coordinates

$$(R(\theta)\cos(\theta),R(\theta)\sin(\theta))$$

and the second:

$$(R(\theta+d\theta)\cos(\theta+d\theta),R(\theta+d\theta)\sin(\theta+d\theta))\, .$$

I am not sure how to proceed from here. I think what one has to do is consider the tension in the string. Calculate the component of the tension in the direction normal the curve for both points and let $d\theta$ go to zero.

Is this sketch correct?

Comment: Usually, we limit ourselves to small displacements with respect to equilibrium. Would this be the case in your example and if so, how can a curved string be at equilibrium ?

Comment: @VincentFraticelli Good question. Yes, well the circle must be the equilibrium configuration in that case and one would have to consider deformations of that circle.

Comment: Would one need a good understanding of Analysis on manifolds for this problem?

Comment: @VincentFraticelli of you think of cell membranes these are usually curved. But there has to be a force which keeps it in that shape.

Comment: I am not sure that you can have a string with circular shape. Waves in strings work because they are tensioned at both ends. In a circle you don't have this option. You might have something that is beam-like, that is, with bending stiffness.

Comment: @nicoguaro Hi. Good point. I personally want to actually model the elastic properties of a cell membrane. So that I could analyse waves on it.

Comment: Oh, in that case, I think that it can be modeled as a shell. The 1-manifold analog would be a beam, then. I will add one formulation as an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure that you can have a string with a circular shape. Waves in strings work because they are tensioned at both ends. In a circle, you don't have this option. You might need something that can withstand lateral forces, that is, it should have bending stiffness. This is the case of a curved beam.

In a curved beam, you have coupling between lateral (radial) and tangential (angular) stresses. It is somewhat, the combined effects of a bar subjected to axial load and a beam.

If we consider small deformations for a a beam with an undeformed configuration that is circular with radius $R$, we obtain the following equation
\begin{align*}
  \frac{EA}{R^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\theta^2}
  + \frac{D}{R^4}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\theta^2}
  + \frac{EA}{R^2}\frac{\partial w}{\partial\theta}
  - \frac{D}{R^4}\frac{\partial^3 w}{\partial\theta^3}
  - \rho A\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2} = -p_\theta\\
  \frac{EA}{R^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\theta}
  - \frac{D}{R^4}\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial\theta^3}
  + \frac{D}{R^4}\frac{\partial^4 w}{\partial\theta^4}
  + \frac{EA}{R^2}w - \rho A\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2} = p_n
\end{align*}
where $u$ is the longitudinal displacement, $w$ the transverse displacement, $\rho$ the mass density, $E$ the Young modulus, $A$ the cross-sectional area, $D~=~Ebh^3/12$ the bending stiffness, $p_\theta$ the force in the longitudinal direction, $p_n$ the transverse force, and $\theta$ the angle in clock-wise direction.

See that this problem is a sixth-order (coupled) PDE.

### References

- Leissa, Arthur W., and Mohamad S. Qatu. Vibrations of continuous systems. McGraw-Hill Education, 2011.

Comment: Very impressive. Thanks for your answer. I'm going to check out that book.